# Printing contents of a nested array

Tags: php, mongodb, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am trying to print the contents of a nested array, but it simply returns "Array" as a string yet will not iterate with a foreach loop. The arrays are coming from a mongodb find(). The dataset looks like this:

```
User
Post_Title
Post_Content[content1,content2,content3]
```

I am trying to get at the content1,2,3.

My current code looks like this:

```
$results = $collection->find($query);

foreach ($results as $doc)
    {
    echo $doc['title']; //this works
    $content[] = $doc['content'];           
    print_r($content); //this prints "Array ( [0] => Array )"
    foreach ($content as $item)
        {
        echo $item;
        }
    }
```

All this code does is print the Title, followed by Array ( [0] => Array ), followed by Array.

I feel quite stupid to not figure out something that seems so basic. Most posts on stack overflow refer to multidimensional associative arrays - in this case, the top level array is associative, but the content array is indexed.

I have also tried

```
foreach ($doc['content'] as $item)
```

But that gives

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I even tried iterating over the returned array again using a nested foreach, like the following:

```
foreach ($results as $doc)
    {
    echo $doc['title']; //this works
    $content[] = $doc['content'];           
    print_r($content); //this prints "Array ( [0] => Array )"
    foreach ($content as $item)
        {
            foreach ($item as $next_item)
                {
                  echo $next_item;
                }
        echo $item;
        }
    }
```

The second foreach failed with an invalid argument.. 
Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

edit: perhaps it has something to do with how I am inserting the data to the DB. That code looks like this

```
$title = $_POST['list_title'];
$content[] = $_POST['list_content1'];
$content[] = $_POST['list_content2'];
$content[] = $_POST['list_content3'];

$object = new Creation();
$object->owner = "$username";
$object->title = "$title";
$object->content = "$content";
$object->insert();
```

Is this not the proper way to add an array as a property to a class?

Comment: have you tried $content[0] instead of $content ?

Comment: I actually just tried `print_r($doc['content'][0]);` and it returned the letter A. I think it may be returning the proper data, but Mongo has literally saved my object array data as the string "Array" instead of the contents of array. Checking the mongo console seems to confirm this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the code that you are saving data. You should replace the following line

$object->content = "$content";

with

$object->content = $content;

Comment: Thank you kind sir, this looks to be the answer.. It was in fact saving the string "Array" instead of the actual array to the object.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is some of array content is an array while other parts are strings. You should test for the sub content `$doc` being an array using [is_array()](http://php.net/is_array). If it is, loop through the `$doc` like you would any other array, and if it isn't, you can echo the content (may need to test the content type before doing this if you're uncertain as to what content it can be)